# chinese character work on localhost but not live server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, character-encoding, ftp

On my localhost I have a language switcher, which changes between English, Chinese and Japanese. The language files are read from csv files (which I saved from Google spreadsheet)

It works fine on my localhost.

I uploaded my site (via beanstalkapp and have tried via ftp also) and the characters are not appearing.

in the uploaded files appears "¿¿¿¿".

How can I get the files to my server without losing the information, i've tried uploaded in binary mode via filezilla, still no luck.  I'm not sure if its the upload process or my Server.

My server is Ubuntu, hosted with Linode. locale -a shows:

```
en_AG
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_NG
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: I just downloaded the file from the server to my desktop and the chinese characters are still there, so i don't think the file is being altered during the ftp process

Comment: Turns out it was a php function fgetcsv()

Comment: do you use `.htaccess` for apacha configration ?

Comment: hi i am facing the same issue. how did you solved it? You were using csv?

Comment: i simply didn't use fgetcsv() used fgets() and explode() instead

Answer (score 0):

You can tar you file, upload and then untar on your server. 
And you can use md5sum to make sure your files are not changed after the uploading.

And which software you are using to view the files on your server?

Comment: its vim, i opened it in utf8 mode